# NS-3 Flow-Monitor - How to deal with number of nodes

Tags: ns-3

In flow-monitor module there's wifi-olsr-flowmon.py, why it always square the number of nodes? Is there any special reason for it?

```
NUM_NODES_SIDE = 3
```

When we give 3 as the number of nodes per side it creates the network for 9 nodes. Can anyone explain how it works and what's the speciality?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply because for this scenario the topology of the nodes is a NxN grid, where N is the number of nodes that you give as input. 
As the variable suggests, that is the number of nodes per side.